# How to stop slider images linking to posts - using anythingSlider on Wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress, slider

I am using Wordpress and the anythingSlider.
When you click on an image on the slider you are directed to a post.

I do not want this to happen.  I only have pages.

How can I disable any linking of the images to the posts?

I have tried to find some a  tag in the code but to no avail.

Anyone got an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i figured it out.  Not sure why it works but it does.

change the permalinks custom